# No corner table with colored titles

Tags: tables, multirow, highlighting

I would like to know how to build a table like the one on this code, however I feel there should be a much better way to do it since:

1.- I want to get rid of the top left cell.
2.- Since the left column should be in dark background there must be a way to do it all at once instead cell by cell (just as in the column case with the line \rowcolor{darkgray})

Thank you in advance!
Any help is welcome

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\rowcolor{darkgray}
\cellcolor{white} & \color{white}{\textbf{A}} & \color{white}{\textbf{B}}\\
\hline
\cellcolor{darkgray}\color{white}{\textbf{C}} & 1 & 2 \\ 
\hline
\cellcolor{darkgray}\color{white}{\textbf{D}} & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some text}
\end{table}
```

Comment: No answer, but a suggestion: if you don't want it to float, then don't use a float, e.g. do not use `table` and `H`. Instead, use `center` environment and `captionof`

Comment: @MiguelGarcia - please see if the answer below meets you requirement

Answer (score 4):

Since colors are used in row / columns I have omitted vertical/ horizontal lines

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{table}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
    \centering
    \caption{\texttt{Table}}
    \label{label1}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{lcc}[code-before = \rowcolor{gray}{1} \columncolor{gray} 
       {1}\cellcolor{white}{1-1}]
                                    &   \color{white}{\textbf{A}} & 
                                                           \color{white}\textbf{B}\\

        \color{white}{\textbf{A}}   &       1                     & 2\\ 

        \color{white}{\textbf{B}}   &       3                     & 4\\  
                
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With standard `tabular` and `xcolor` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{darkgray}}c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-3}
\rowcolor{darkgray}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{white}}           
                            & \color{white}{\textbf{A}} 
                                & \color{white}{\textbf{B}}\\
    \hline
\color{white}{\textbf{C}}   & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
\color{white}{\textbf{D}}   & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some text}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit simplified code for a standard tabular:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
\gdef\rowfonttype{#1}#1\ignorespaces%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| >{\columncolor{darkgray}\bfseries\color{white}}c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{darkgray} 
\cellcolor{white} & \color{white}\bfseries A & \color{white}\bfseries B \\
\hline
C & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
D & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]